# Submit response to Other field in MultipleChoiceItem

Tags: google-apps-script

My form contains one MultipleChoiceItem (Radio button) with the following options:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- Other ...

I would like to post a response to the 'Other' field.

My script looks like this:

```
var existingForm = FormApp.openById('INSERT_FORM_ID');
var formItems = existingForm.getItems();
var myItemResponse = formItems[0].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("5");
var formResponse = existingForm.createResponse();
formResponse.withItemResponse(myItemResponse);
formResponse.submit();
```

The form is submitted and i can see the response with value '5' listed in the summary report of Google Forms. But when i browse to the individual submitted forms this Radio button appears to have an empty response (The Other field is not even checked).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse). `Creates a new response to the form. To answer a question item, create an` [`ItemResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response.html) `from the item, then attach it to this form response by calling` [`FormResponse.withItemResponse(response)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response.html#withItemResponse(ItemResponse)). I think what you are missing is the use of Class **`ItemResponse`**. Try to use the code provided there.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 But `formItems[0].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("5");` creates an ItemResponse which i store in `var myItemResponse` which in turn i provide to `formResponse.withItemResponse(myItemResponse);`. I am sorry if i misunderstood your reply.